# an error during a type conversion in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I’m studying Swift Animation. Its material is written in Swift 2, so I had to convert its original code into Swift 3. I have learned from it along, but now I have a big problem. Xcode successfully built this code but produced a runtime error message. [(I attached the image file.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oCOF.png)

I can’t solve this at all on my own as I guess I have little experience. How can I fix this? Help.

```
func setQuote() {

    //fadeOut


    //getting data from API
    let dataService = DataService()
    dataService.getQuoteData {(quote, author) -> Void in

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {

            //fadeIn and backgroundColor


            //quote
            self.quoteLabel.text = quote


            //author - optional binding

            //if no author


            }, completion:nil)


    }
}


class DataService {

    func getQuoteData(_ completion: @escaping (_ quote: String, _ author: String?) -> ()) {

        let url = URL(string: "http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&lang=en&format=json")!

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { ( data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            do {
                let jsonDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

                let aQuote = jsonDictionary["quoteText"] as! String
                let aAuthor = jsonDictionary["quoteAuthor"] as! String

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                    completion(aQuote, aAuthor)
                })

            } catch {
                print("invalid json query")
            }
        } as! (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void).resume()
    }

}
```

Comment: U missed a bracket? should be `((Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void)`

Comment: No. the open bracket starts at "URLSession.shared.dataTask("

Comment: why need `as! (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void` anyway? U can just remove it and use .resume()

Comment: I can't. When I remove it, Xcode says,
Cannot convert value of type '(Data?, URLResponse?, NSError?) -> Void' to expected argument type '(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void'
Fix-it: Insert "as! (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void"

Comment: 1. which line generates that error? 2. In your console, there is always a line that conveys a more meaningful *reason*...you just have to scroll up and find that and paste that info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try rewrite it like this

```
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        do {
            let jsonDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

            let aQuote = jsonDictionary["quoteText"] as! String
            let aAuthor = jsonDictionary["quoteAuthor"] as! String

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                completion(aQuote, aAuthor)
            })

        } catch {
            print("invalid json query")
        }
    }

    task.resume()
```

or simply change the `( data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void` to `( data, response, error) -> Void` and remove the `as! ...`

Comment: OMG.. Thanks, Tj3n. :) You made my day. I'll try to keep up my work and help someone else like you did.